# SQL QUERY, what can't appear in the having clause?

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have the following relation:

```
R(A, B, C, D, E)
```

and the following query

```
SELECT ...
     FROM R
     WHERE ...
     GROUP BY B, E
     HAVING ???
```

What can't appear in the having clause?: MAX(C), COUNT(A), D,B

I believe all of them work, but I am little bit hesitant about B. MAX(C) works because we can bound the max value of the column c in a group. Same thing for COUNT(A). D also works. It's just an attribute, but it looks weird to bound a member of the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: D should not work. Because you use `GROUP BY B, E`, so in HAVING, all other columns other than B, E must appear with an aggregate functions_ so MAX(c) and COUNT(a) should work, and D should not. D will raise error like `not a group by expression`

Comment: Let see that D=age and you just want ages less than 30. How do you constrain that in each group. I thought that HAVING clause was the same thing as the WHERE clause.

Comment: HAVING only go with GROUP BY and it means as where_aggregate_functions_of_group_by so you can use `HAVING MAX(age) < 30`. In WHERE clause you cannot use `WHERE MAX(age) < 30`.

Comment: @HardWorker: Think of this as three steps: First you find data with `FROM/JOIN` and `WHERE`. Then you aggregate your data (summing, counting, etc. per B and E). Then you apply the `HAVING` clause to this intermediate result set, so as to finally filter your results. (E.g.: 1. Select all employees. 2. Group by department; count employees per department. 3. Dismiss departments with an employee count less then ten.)

Answer (score 0):

According to standard SQL, when aggregating records (which is what you do with `GROUP BY`), you can select

- the fields you group by. (Of course, if I group by employee and department, i.e. want a result row per employee and department, I can show the two in the result.)
- aggregations, such as sums, counts, etc. (If I group by department, I can count the employees or sum up their salaries and show these in the result.)
- fields that are functionally dependent on the grouped by columns. (If I group by unique employee number, I can also show the employes name for instance.)

Many DBMS don't support the latter case, however (and force you to redundantly put the employee name in the `GROUP BY` clause or to clumsily pseudo-aggregate, e.g. `MIN(name)` though there only is one name per employee number of course).

What can appear in the `HAVING` clause? All columns and expressions that you can select.

1. `MAX(C)`. Yes you find the maximum `C` per `B` and `E`.
2. `COUNT(A)`. Yes. You count all records per `B` and `E` where `A` is not null.
3. `D`. Only if D is dependent on `B` and `E`. The DBMS will see this from unique constraints on the table, i.e. if `B` or `E` or `B`+`E` is unique for the table, you can select `D`. (Provided the DBMS is standard-compliant here.)
4. `B`. Yes. That is the `B` that you group by. Of course you can show it or use it in `HAVING`.